# Where can I specify warn-on-reflection in a clj file?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to use  warn-on-reflection  in a clj file. When I write:

```
(set! warn-on-reflection true)
```

: after the ns declaration I get the error:

```
 java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: warn-on-reflection in this context
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Global variables are conventionally named with names that start and end with asterisk.

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
```

I guess you copied that from a forum which makes such text bold.

---

Update: add these lines in your leiningen project.clj:

```
  ;; Emit warnings on all reflection calls.
  :global-vars {*warn-on-reflection* true}
```

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj

Comment: When I use this line in the clj file I get the error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change/establish root binding of: *warn-on-reflection* with set "

Comment: _warn-on-reflection_ in project.clj is now deprecated ([link](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/eval.clj) - line 335)

Comment: Only `:warn-on-reflection` was deprecated, \*warn-on-reflection\* can still be added in the `:global-vars` parameter.

Answer (score 11):

The `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)` is probably the way to go.  If you do want to use lein-specific methods to do this, here is some updated info for 2.x:

To set the global in the project definition:

```
(defproject foo ...
  :global-vars {*warn-on-reflection* true}
  ...)
```

Or just periodically run `lein check`, as it will warn on reflection.

Comment: +1 for `lein check`. `*warn-on-reflection*` wasn't giving any errors, but the profiler was saying that 10% of the time was spent calling `getMethods`. `lein check` showed that the issue was the random helpers from my main personal library (whoops).